# RDS connectivity in Python using Boto3 and IAM Role

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to my RDS MySQL DB via Python. I am using the Boto3 library. The issue that I am facing is while trying to connect to the DB via the IAM Token generation method. I don't have a user created in IAM but have a role created and assigned.

When I try to connect to the DB, the code fails as it's expecting to have a key-pair stored in the .aws/configuration file. Snippet below.

```
# gets the credentials from .aws/credentials
# session = boto3.Session(profile_name='xyz')
client = boto3.client('rds',region_name='eu-west-2')

token = client.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname=ENDPOINT, Port=PORT, DBUsername=USR,Region='eu-west-2')
print(token)
```

Getting the below error.

```
    raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

But since I cannot use an IAM user and a role cannot have a key-pair attached to it, I am not sure how to execute this and get this done. Any suggestions would be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont have a user created in IAM but have a role created and assigned.

If you have only IAM role for RDS, you still need IAM user or some other role (e.g. instance role) which can **assume** (`iam:AssumeRole`) the RDS's role.

Then, you have to use boto3' [assume_role](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role) to get temp credentials which you can then use to create new boto3 session for your RDS.

Comment: I tried this approach but it still says it needs creds for an existing User or another role. I checked the official AWS documentation as well and it says the same.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html

Here is the snippet from the above link.

# The calls to AWS STS AssumeRole must be signed with the access key ID
# and secret access key of an existing IAM user or by using existing temporary 
# credentials such as those from another role.

Comment: @karD Yes, you can't assume role if you don't have credentials for the IAM user who want's to assume it in the first place.

Comment: but isn't that defeating my original purpose? Since I cannot use a user and only use a Role to connect to the RDS instance via python just like in Java.

Comment: Sadly, this is the only way for IAM user to assume a role. But  maybe your role is meant for instances, containers or lambda functions at AWS, not IAM users? In that case you don't need extra credentials.

Comment: My aim is to have a Python piece running on Lambda to connect to a RDS instance without having the need to use an IAM User and use only IAM role as I do not want to hardcode any sort of creds in the code. Assume role/token generation would have resolved it but again, no hardcoded creds anywhere.

Comment: Yes, makes sense if its for lambda, as I wrote. So make sure your role is set as execution role for your lambda function. Nothing else is needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229963/discussion-between-kard-and-marcin).

Answer (score 0):

You should check the role of your User first.
Then, it should be .aws/credentials

```
cat credential
[default]
aws_access_key_id = *****
aws_secret_access_key = ****
```

Comment: Unless I am understanding your solution wrongly, it won't work. I cannot use an IAM user due to certain limitations.